# UTC Timestamp conversion

Tags: android, simpledateformat, utc

I am working with an application where I have `DateAndTimePicker`, from which I can get `date` and `time` in a specified format. Now I need to convert this date and time string to `UTC timestamp` format. I tried a lot but couldn't find the solutions.

`UTC` format should be like this `"2015-05-01T08:56:53.891Z"`

I tried code like this

```
public static String getdateUTCFormat(String date, String time) {
    try {

        DateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date utcDate = utcFormat.parse(date + time);

        Log.v("Date And Time-----------",utcDate.toString());
        return utcDate.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the values of`date` and `time`? What is the current behavior of your code?

Comment: Maybe you need `utcFormat.parse(date + 'T' + time)` ?!